# embedded razor pages inside razor class library

Tags: asp.net-core

after publish web application, all razor views or pages in RCLs, will copied to output directory. how we can prevent this behavior and use embedded view/pages
for example this is structure of solution

WebApp => WebApp/Pages/Index.razor

RCL => MyRazorClassLibrary/Areas/Account/Login.razor

after publish webapp, output folder contains

Areas/Account/Login.razor

dotnet 6
Folder publish

Comment: Where do you publish your web application? What's your version of  your web application ?

Comment: @QingGuo dotnet 6, folder publish